# Adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

Nothing happens when I tap on my `MPMoviePlayerController`. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in setting up the `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

```
- (void) playMovie : (NSString *) urlString{

    self.movieURLString = urlString;

    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.movieURLString];

    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL.absoluteURL];
    [self.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.movieView.frame;

    /* add tap handler */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showControls:)];
    singleFingerTap.delegate = self;

    //EDIT: this line somehow didn't make into my OP
    [self.moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    self.moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    // respond to changes in movie player status
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayer];

}

- (void) showControls : (UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    NSLog(@"here");
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

}
```

Comment: I did not check the details of your post but I guess you are missing the fact that the `MPMoviePlayerController` uses a couple of gesture recognizers itself and yours will never get triggered due to conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You never added the gesture recognizer to a view, that's what's wrong.

```
[self.moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

There's also no need to set the delegate unless you're going to implement some of the methods in the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

Comment: Somehow this didn't make it into the code that I posted. I tried this, but still no response. I don't get it. Thanks!